# Confused about how OneDrive works

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I am using windows10 on several PCs all with the same microsoft account.

My understanding is I have a OneDrive cloud storage, and on every PC I can see a local OneDrive, which will be synchronized to the cloud, is that right?

Now I have some questions.

1. Those local OneDrive are supposed to use my local harddisk storage.
   So if I put a lot of files in the Cloud, I will have a local copy in
   all my PCs which occupied my local hard disk?
2. If I modified something on my local OneDrive, say I delete a file,
   the file in the Cloud will later be deleted as well when they
   synchronise ?
3. If I do different modifications on different PCs locally, which one
   will be synchronised to the Cloud?
4. I tried to use browser to login my OneDrive, in this way I am
   supposed to be see the Cloud files, not the files on my local
   OneDrive, right? But I see different directories different files
   when visit it using different PCs.

I am really completely confused by how OneDrive work. Anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

OneDrive, Google Drive, DropBox, etc. all work in the same way.  You create an account and install the client on your PC.

1. OneDrive will create a folder on your PC.  Anything you save in that folder gets uploaded autmatically in the background to the cloud storage on the internet.  If you put files directly into the cloud storage, they will be automatically downloaded to the folder on your PC.
2. If you delete a file locally, OneDrive will delete the file in the cloud, as well as from any computers linked with that account.  So if you have two PCs with OneDrive, and you delete a file from either PC or the cloud, that file gets deleted everywhere.
3. Every action is time-stamped.  Whichever action was the last will take precedence.  OneDrive has some "smarts" built into it.  If you modified a file offline, and another online, it will warn you the files are out of sync and will ask you which is the file to keep.
4. Im not sure what you are meaning in this question.  You would browse to https://onedrive.live.com to access your files if you are not on your local computer.  This allows you to see anything you saved while away from home.  The files you see there, are the same files on your PC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if say I put 1T of things on the Cloud, and I only have a 500G harddisk. What happen?

Comment: My 4-th question is, I tried to use browsers on different PCs to visit the Cloud. But I see different things stored there.

Comment: Well, you will have some issues.  OneDrive will try to download all the files and fill up your computer's drive.  If you plan on doing that, you will need to turn off the syncing to the computer.  Right click the OneCloud icon in the task tray, go to settings, then the account tab, and select unlink OneDrive

Comment: I cannot fine the OneCloud icon in the task tray. Is there any other ways to unlink?